# MVC - Creating View that lists products from database using stored procedure that passes search parameter from textbox

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-5

I hope the wording on the Title isn't confusing..I tried to be as specific as possible...

**Goal**

Create a View that allows a customer to search products using a textbox from the Index View on my SearchController. When the customer clicks the search button, it will redirect to the Search View that should take the string from the textbox, use it as the @param for my stored procedure, then return the Search View as a list (table).

**Problem**

I'm very new to MVC, and I can get something of the nature without using stored procedures, but the project I'm working on requires a stored procedure to be used.

Also, currently the search button doesn't go to the Search View().

**Code**

My SearchController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using StoreFront.Models;

namespace StoreFront.Controllers
{
    public class SearchController : Controller
    {
        private ProductContext Productdb = new ProductContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Search(string search)
        {
           return View(Productdb.Products.Where(x => x.ProductName.Contains(search) && x.IsPublished == true).ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

Index() View:

```
@model IEnumerable<StoreFront.Models.Products>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_CustomerLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Get))
        {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Input product to search for: </label>
            @Html.TextBox("search")
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="SearchButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
        </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSearchProducts] 
    @SearchText varchar(500)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT ProductName,Price,ImageFile FROM Product WHERE ProductName = @SearchText AND IsPublished = 1

END
```

I have created an spSearchProductsModel.edmx that has the stored procedure, whose function name is `GetProducts()` that returns a complex of `spSearchProductsModel_Result`

I have been stuck on this for a looong time, and I have tried browsing the extend of Youtube + earlier stack questions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Let me know if you need me to post anymore code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Get))
```

... is telling the form to submit to the `Index` action of the `Search` controller.  Thus, your Search action is never being hit.

Instead, change that to:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Search", FormMethod.Get))
```

And see how that works for you.

Debugging tip: put a breakpoint in your search action on the controller and you can verify at least that the correct action is being hit.  If not, you either aren't calling it correctly, don't have the correct verb, or were not able to pass the model correctly.  (a tool like Fiddler is invaluable for helping determine the cause of these types of errors).

On a separate note, I don't think your database call will act as expected.  Calling stored procedures is slightly different (usually) than using Entity Framework to read from tables.  You're doing the usual "read from a table" method, which is fine if you want to read from tables (that's preferred).  To call a stored procedure, usually it looks like this:

```
return View(Productdb.Database.Query<ReturnObject>(
    "ProcedureName", 
    new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@SearchText", search)
    ).ToList());
```

One of the trickier parts about using stored procedures is that you must have a type (shown as `ReturnObject` in the `Query<ReturnObject>` portion) set up to map exactly to the return columns of the procedure.  Typically easier to use the native table method as you are attempting, because EF generally sets all that up for you. (take that with a grain of salt though, I don't usually use the edmx stuff so I may be wrong, but I'm near certain the code you have is reading from a table)

On yet another note, ensure that you have the proper views in place.  Based on your code, you should have a Search.cshtml view set up taking an `IEnumerable<>` of whatever type you're passing to it.  By default, if the view name is omitted, the engine searches for a view of the same name as the action method.  I prefer to be explicit and pass both the view name and the model (where the model is in a separate variable usually, for readability):

```
public ActionResult Search(string search) {

    var model = Productdb.Database.Query<ReturnObject>(
        "ProcedureName", 
        new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@SearchText", search)
        ).ToList();

     return View("Search", model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you action method to use post attribute.

```
   [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string search)
        {
            //Current code here
          }
```

Replace

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Get))
```

with

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search"))
```

You should be able to go to search action now.

Comment: I did, and for some reason it is still not switching over to Search/Search, it stays on Index